# How to make a many to one relationship in oracle apex?

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I have two tables work and projects. The column that they have in commen is row_id. how do i take the row_id from work and use it in projects also?

Comment: What do you mean by "use"? Are you trying to join the tables via that column?

Comment: no i want the Row_id to be the same in both tables not join them

Comment: why do you want them to be the same?

Comment: How would you match a work row to a project row in order to make the Row_ids the same? Additionally, can you post an example of your data and demonstrate how you would like them to look?

Comment: If the row_id's are the same in each table (Warning! "rowid" is a reserved Oracle name and can easily be confused with your custom column) I don't see how it can be a many-to-one relationship... is row_id a primary or unique key in both tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Foreign key constraint on row_id in project table,

for foreign key constraint refer [ORACLE/PLSQL: FOREIGN KEYS](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_keys.php)

Hope this Helps..